# QAbstractItemModel dataChanged warning

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a MVC pattern data model `class NeighborsModel : public QAbstractTableModel`. I redefined method `setData` and emit signal `dataChanged` at the end. But this signal gives me a runtime warning:

*QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector'
(Make sure 'QVector' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)*.

I believe this is a wrong behavior, but I can't figure out what's wrong, because I do as the pattern says. I doubt I should register QVector as a metatype.

```
bool NeighborsModel::setData(const QModelIndex & index, const QVariant & value, int role)
{
    ...
    emit dataChanged(index,index);
    return true;
}
```

dataChanged signal prototype

```
Q_SIGNALS:
    void dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = QVector<int>());
```

upd:
I solved the case by adding to the `NeighborsModel` constructor, but I'm not sure this is the best practice.

```
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK( 5, 0, 0 )
    if (QMetaType::type("QVector<int>") == QMetaType::UnknownType)
#else
    if (QMetaType::type("QVector<int>") == 0
        || !QMetaType::isRegistered(QMetaType::type("QVector<int>")))
#endif
    {
        qRegisterMetaType<QVector<int>>("QVector<int>");
    }
```

Comment: You have a QueuedConnection connected to your dataChanged() signal which means the data types for the signal must be stored somewhere. This can only be done when you properly register them all with qRegisterMetaType() as the warning says. QModelIndex is already registered internally by Qt but QVector<int> is not - you have to do it by yourself or don't use a QueuedConnection here.

Comment: Thank you @chehrlic I have no explicit connection to this signal, but there is a separate thread that calls `NeighborsModel::setData`. Is it where the `QueuedConnection` might appear?

Comment: At least it looks like you're doing something wrong. The model should only be accessed in the main thread.

Comment: Where do you use this model? Do you use it in your QML code? If so, your model's object must reside in the UI thread. Your QML connects to this signal and it became queued because the thread is different.